# Is there a function for removing dashes from a string of numbers, without removing leading zeros?

Tags: sas

I would like to remove dashes from 3 to 9 digit numbers. A certain percentage of those numbers have leading zeros in them. I tried using the Compress function, but this stripped the zeros as well. What would be the best function to use?

Comment: Numbers cannot have dashes in them.  The COMPRESS() function will only remove the characters you tell it to remove, so it will not remove the `0` character unless you tell it to remove it. Are you sure you didn't accidentally convert the string into a numeric variable instead?

Comment: We are not talking about numbers, but about stings of digits and dashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your "numbers" are actually codes with digits and dashes and you want to keep only the digits, so what you need is string processing.

The `compress` function in SAS has a second (optional) parameter. If you don't specify it, the function will remove all white space characters. If you do, it will remove the characters specified. So try

```
no_dash = compress(with_dash, '-');
```

Alternatively you could remove all non digit characters, using a third (also optional) parameter

```
no_dash = compress(with_dash, '0123456789', 'k');
```

The `k` specifies to keep instead of remove the characters specified. You can shorten this by adding the `d` to the third parameter, telling SAS to add all digits to the second:

```
no_dash = compress(with_dash, '', 'dk');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have stored the compressed result (with implicit conversion) in a numeric variable, that variable may need a format to get the result you want.

```
data _null_;
  my_dashed_text = '000-90-123';
  my_compressed_text = compress(my_dashed_text, '-');

  attrib my_num_var 
    length = 8
    format = z9.
  ;
  my_num_var = compress(my_dashed_text, '-');

  put (_all_) (=/);
run;

------ LOG -----

NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values at the places given by:
      (Line):(Column).
      36:16

my_dashed_text=000-90-123
my_compressed_text=00090123
my_num_var=000090123
```

The `Z` numeric format tells SAS to add leading zeros that fill out to the specified width *when displaying the number*.    The format is a fixed width, so a my_num_var from both `"123-456"` and `"0-1-2-3-45-6"` will display a `Z9` formatted value of `000123456`.  SAS formatting can't make a number value look like `123456` or `0123456` when rendered through a single format specification (such a `Z9`)